# Is the React Native component hierarchy documented anywhere? If so, where or how?

Tags: react-native

I can't find any inheritance diagrams (or any documentation at all) of what components inherit from.

For instance, it seems that TouchableWithoutFeedback is the parent superclass of TouchableHighlight and TouchableOpacity (because TouchableWithoutFeedback contains the methods onPressIn and onPressOut).

I'm looking for something like the bottom half of [this inheritance chain documentation](https://docs.fusetools.com/fuse/controls/button.html) (for a different technology) that lists all the superclass methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to dive into the source code. But as a guide, no component inherits from any other Component. Every component just extends `Component` or maybe `PureComponent`.

For instance here is `TouchableNativeFeedback` - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/b7bb2e5745f2bdbfeeccef8d97d469730942e01c/Libraries/Components/Touchable/TouchableNativeFeedback.android.js

Yes some of the props are shared between components, like `View` `ScrollView`. And as you mentioend above. but this is not due to inheritance. The docs make this clear by using spread operator on props. For instance:

The text component: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#style

Has same style properties as `View` as indicatated by `View Style Props...`:

[image]

Same with the `TouchableNativeFeedback` it has `TouchableWithoutFeedback props...` - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablenativefeedback.html#props :

[image]