# Inspect React Native component hierarchy from Objective-C/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

From the context of a 3rd party iOS framework, I'd like to get the React Native component hierarchy.

I see the `RCTCxxBridge` has this method: `- (void)enqueueJSCall:(NSString *)module method:(NSString *)method args:(NSArray *)args completion:(dispatch_block_t)completion` which calls through to `callJSFunction` in C++, but this method takes a module/method/args, and not an arbitrary JS string like a JSContext (which React Native no longer uses). Is there a way I can run JS from ObjC/Swift in React Native's JS context, and get the component hierarchy?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49658247/11212074 You'll have to dive into the source code. But as a guide, no component inherits from any other Component

Comment: I'm interested in the UI layout hierarchy, not the inheritance hierarchy